# Creating a Julia DataFrame with long ColumnName

Tags: dataframe, julia

i am trying to create `DataFrame` in Julia using:
`df2 = DataFrame(A = 1:5)`and its all right.

Now i want to create `df = DataFrame("Amount") = 1:5)` but it returns an error.  I tried many thing and cant create a DataFrame with column names like "Amount", " Class Problem" etc..

How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=>` syntax instead, e.g.:

```
DataFrame("Amount" => 1:5, "Class Problem" => "const")
```